# Can anymote protocol be used to communicate between two android devices?

Tags: google-tv

I am trying to control one android device using another. And for doing this I want to include the ANYMOTE protocol in my implementation.
As per my understanding I can use the already existing "Google TV android remote" app as my client on one of the devices. 
But what I am stuck up with is,that do I need to implement the server side by my self ?? 
OR
Is there an existing implementation (The one used in Google TV) of the same, freely availbale, which I can integrate in my android device and customize it

Answer (score 1):

Google has not open-sourced the server side of their Anymote implementation for Google TV. However, the protocol is fully documented: https://developers.google.com/tv/remote/docs/anymote

Anymote was designed for IP remote controls. So, depending on your use case, it might not necessarily be the way to control one Android device from another. Also, the Anymote server needs to do system-level touch and key event injection which is not allowed by third-party apps, only by system-level apps signed by Google.

Comment: "Google has not open-sourced the server side of their Anymote implementation for Google TV." still it is true?